# Wordpress Login page showing blank

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a wordpress custom theme. 
It was working fine. But suddenly a problem cropped up. The login page is showing blank and I can not access my Dashboard. The site is : http://shoulderdoctor.in

What is the funny thing is that before uploading my files in this host I was working live on another url which is http://damiracle.net/abheekkardemo/

In the second url the login page is showing but in the actual site url the login page is showing a blank screen.
I have Googled for the solutions and searched in this forum also. Followed the instructions like renamed plugin folders, theme folders. 
But also the problem persists.

So being frustrated I am seeking help from you. 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://shoulderdoctor.in/wp-login.php is working. I could access, It wasn't blank.

Answer (score 0):

http://shoulderdoctor.in/wp-login.php

It look sas though you removed the login widget in your php. This page should allow you to get to your dashboard though.

Answer (score 0):

First of all on above both link work fine as in front side and dashboard side .

please check in your end.

This link is open admin 
http://damiracle.net/abheekkardemo/wp-admin/

Also this link open admin
http://shoulderdoctor.in/wp-admin/

Comment: Thanks everyone for support. I have resolved it. It was problem with the settings.php of the theme which I had edited. Anyway what I did--> Just removed my the edited settings.php and uploaded the actual settings.php of the theme and it worked . Thanks again to you who had put their efforts to view my site.